# How to call custom jQuery plugins into the customizer controls

Tags: jquery, theme-customizer, select

I never tried to use the theme customizer, somehow I don't find that thing good. But recently I tried it, and stuck into this matter.

I extended the Class `WP_Customize_Control` to made my own `<select multiple="multiple">` control, and it's working fine.

Now I want to trigger the [select2 jQuery plugin](https://select2.github.io/) to that particular control so that I can assure good UX using the field.

But I failed. :(

```
<?php
function wpse20170307_customize_preview_js() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2', get_template_directory_uri() .'/libs/select2/select2.min.css', array(), '4.0.3', 'all' );
    wp_register_script( 'select2', get_template_directory_uri() .'/libs/select2/select2.min.js', array( 'customize-preview' ), '4.0.3', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/customizer.js', array( 'customize-preview', 'select2' ), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'wpse20170307_customize_preview_js' );
```

This action hook isn't enqueuing the necessary plugin scripts or styles either. So putting code like:

```
$('.customize-control-multiple-select select').addClass('some');
```

isn't working at all.

I tried enqueuing select2 using `wp_enqueue_scripts` and using to put the above code into `customizer.js`, but I failed again.

With the customizer called, using the "View Page Source", I found no such select2 things anywhere, but the select2 is properly enqueued with `wp_enqueue_scripts` in the main site.

Is there any way or how can I do so?

### Update - 2017-03-12

With the help of Weston Ruter, I managed to become close to a solution. Here's what I got so far:

```
public $type = 'multiple_select';
```

And enqueued a JS file like below:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'project-customizer-inject', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/project-customizer-inject.js', array( 'customize-controls', 'select2' ), '1.0.0', true );
```

And in this file:

```
// Set up select2 control in this.container...
console.log(control);
control.id = id;
console.log(id); // id is not defined
//control.select2(); // function select2 not found
//id.select2(); // not working, as id is not set
```

`console.log(control);` returned:

[image: js-console-child]

Issue is, I'm not *that* good at JavaScripts. So, I cannot get through the object I got with `controls`. And `select2` plugin cannot be found within that `ready: function() {}`.

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to enqueue JS in the customizer *controls*, you need to use the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` action. This is different than the action used to enqueue scripts into the customizer *preview*, which is what themes normally do via `customize_preview_init` or `wp_enqueue_scripts`. So in your snippet above, replace `customize_preview_init` with `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`.

Secondly, in order to extend a control in the customizer you need to wait for the control to be initialized. Controls may be added and removed dynamically in the course of a customizer session, so you cannot just query the DOM once the page is ready. Your custom control should implement a corresponding JS `wp.customize.Control` subclass that is responsible for setting up Select2. For example, if you have:

```
class My_Select2_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
    public $type = 'my_select2';
    /* ... */
}
```

Then you should have a JS file that also contains:

```
wp.customize.controlConstructor.my_select2 = wp.customize.Control.extend( {
    ready: function() {
        var control = this;
        wp.customize.Control.prototype.ready.call( control );
        // Set up select2 control in this.container...
    }
} );
```

Enqueue this file at `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` with `customize-controls` and `select2` as its script dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Already upvoted the answer. But due to lack of necessary knowledge, I got stuck to a point. Updated my question. Any update would be greatly appreciated.